# Jax-rs - add info to first node about max results, offset and results

Tags: java, pagination, jax-rs

I create RESTfull service using jax-rs. It returns xml form lists like:

```
<products>
    <product>
      //some code
    </product>
</products>
```

I trying implement pagination and in first node `<products>` I want add info about max results, offset, and current number of result.

How to add this info?
maybe is better way to show this info?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper for your products with pagination info. Maybe something like this:

```
<productsResult>
<noOfResults>10</noOfResults>
<offset>0</offset>
<products>
    <product>
      //some code
    </product>
</products>
</productsResult>
```

Comment: I add wrapper but now in xml i have node '<products></products>' reopen for every list element, and no '<product></product>' node